# Flag Wave effect in cocos2d-iPhone

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making cocos2d iOS project where I need flag wave effect.
I am trying to fly the flag when the wind blows.
Any suggestions how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Add flag image animation like 10/15 images.

Comment: No, I don't want to use animation, because I can't achieve random wave effect with animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If flag is very important in your app and you need really random waving on your flag, you can use cocos2d with physics (box2d/chipmunk). I posted a box2d example for you. You need create this physics bodies and joints then add texture on them (google it). At last you will need code for waving: (you can use `body->SetLinearVelocity()` and change position of this bodies left/right, up/down randomly to achive waving effect you need). You can add much bodies to get better physics. But this method isn't easy and heavy(cpu).
2. If you using your flag only like decoration you should use animation with 4-5 styles waving and change them randomly.
3. Maybe this video will be helpful: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8qrS-lh0Tg). And library from it [LiquidFun](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/). Elastic bodies looks really cool.

REMEMBER: if you using box2d, don't forget use `bodyDef.gravityScale = 0;` on your flag.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Thanks, I try to do it with LiquidFun, Elastic Particles looks like the exact thing I want. Thanks again